# Will switching to PAYE from IBR reset PSLF qualifying payments?

Tags: united-states, student-loan

I just got my renewed payment for my current IBR plan. I read an article comparing the two plans and it looks as though PAYE would benefit me more than my current IBR plan. The payment estimator on http://studentloans.gov reflects this as well.

If I switch plans will I lose all my PSLF qualifying payments and have to start over or will this carry over to the new plan as well?